# Как добавить тело запроса в формате JSON в esql в ibm integration bus?

Tags: ibm

Всем привет!

С помощью iib ( ibm integration bus ) нужно сделать POST запрос к api одного сервиса.
Проблема заключается в том, что в этот POST запрос в data-raw нужно добавить тело сообщения в формате JSON.
Как правильно сделать в esql ? Может кто помочь?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Сделал esql перед запрос где и поставил в JSON.Data свои значения требуемые